# Help needed with an integration problem.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab

I need to compute the following

\begin{equation}
 J(\sigma) = 1-{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-(\xi-\sigma^2/2)^2/2\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\log [1+e^\xi]d\xi} \tag{*}
\end{equation}

where $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$. I have following questions

1. What kind of function is this?
2. Which numerical method I should look into for computing $J(.)$?
3. Is is possible to compute $J(.)$ in Matlab directly? I tried using integral(.) but it returns me NaN values

I am not a calculus person so I have no progress to show here.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you plot the function you will realize that the function has a finite contribution in an interval of few $\sigma$ (typically for a Gaussian curve, the 99.8% of the curve is in the interval $[-3\sigma,3\sigma]$). I would recomend you to use a simple algorithm to compute the numerical integral, such as the trapezoidal rule, in the interval I have mentioned. I do not undertand the reason for any diverency in the integration

Comment: Thank you for the lead. Plotting functions was very helpful.